# Custom-directive in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a custom-directive **:myMethod="loadProfile(currentUser)"** which loads the JSON when the component is loaded. I use `mapGetters` from `Vuex` but surprisingly, this method is also working very well..I have a dilemma if this is also correct or performance-wise compared to other approaches like calling methods in `mounted` or `created` hooks (which I also tried)? Which is better to call on the hook or custom-directive?

Here is my sample code:

```
  <template v-if="currentUser.username === 'admin'">
       ... //
  <template v-else>
      <div :myMethod="loadProfile(currentUser)"></div>
  </template>
```

**Vuex Getters**

```
  computed: {
     ...mapGetters([
         'currentUser',
     ])
  }
```

**Method**

```
  loadProfile(payload){
        this.user.last_name = payload.last_name,
        this.user.first_name =  payload.first_name,
        this.user.image = ( payload.image === 'no_avatar.png' ? '/image/no_avatar.png' : '/storage/images/'+ payload.image)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use methods unless you really have to. In this case there seems to be little reason to call `loadProfile` without `currentUser`, so lets just move it to a computed property:

```
computed: {
  ...mapGetters([
    'currentUser'
  ]),
  actualUser () {
    // Make a shallow copy
    const user = { ...this.user };

    if (this.currentUser) {
      user.lastName = this.currentUser.lastName;
      user.firstName = this.currentUser.firstName;
      user.image = (this.currentUser.image === 'no_avatar.png' ? '/image/no_avatar.png' : `/storage/images/${this.currentUser.image}`);
    }

    return user;
  }
}
```

Why use a computed property? Computed properties are calculated and updated whenever their dependencies update. When the dependencies stay constant, the computed property will just be loaded from cache. This is a better for performance and makes it so you don't have to worry about when to update your data yourself.

---

As for the use of a directive. I most cases you don't need to use directives. You don't send a function reference to the directive here, but rather the evaluated result of the method, so doing `<div :myMethod="actualUser"></div>` would work too. You may want to make sure that what you are doing cannot be done with actual components. Components are re-usable and much easier to read than the code in a custom directive.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and answer. Now I understand.

Answer (score 1):

Vue.js directives are only meant to do some low-level DOM manipulations that you cannot do with a regular component. So in short, you should not be doing what you are currently doing.

Now on to longer answer:

In your code, you are doing something like this: `<div :myMethod="loadProfile(currentUser)"></div>`. If `:myMethod` is a directive then it should be `v-myMethod=""` instead of `:myMethod=""`. Latter syntax i.e. colon syntax refers to `props` and not directive. So, it means your code is not really executing directive. Just treating `myMethod` as some prop.

Second, doing `:myMethod="loadProfile(currentUser)"` doesn't mean you are doing anything within an actual directive code. It is still being called from the component template.

Third, if we look at your `loadProfile()` method implementation, then it is not a function that **returns a value**. It is simply a function modifying component instance using `this`. If all you need to do this, then you don't need a directive or prop.

Fourth, doing `:myMethod="loadProfile(currentUser)"` will work but it looks awkward definitely not readable. Instead, you should rely on a watcher or computed property. It is the idiomatic way of doing things in Vue.js. Example watcher implementation would look like:

```
watch: {
    currentUser(newVal) {
        this.user.last_name = newVal.last_name,
        this.user.first_name =  newVal.first_name,
        this.user.image = ( newVal.image === 'no_avatar.png' ? '/image/no_avatar.png' : '/storage/images/'+ newVal.image)
    }
```

}

As far as the performance is concerned, you should not worry about it. Performance penalty if any will be negligible.

Comment: Thanks bro, appreciate the clarification.